# Play Framework 2 best way to store password hash of user

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I've got an add user option in my app. I'd like to store the user pass in hash format in the database. Th password is stored in plain text format in the sample codes included with the framework. 
After some searching i've found out that there's a Crypto.encryptAES() function implemented in play2 that can be used to secure passwords.

My question is what's the best place to use it? And how to use it to create the most maintainable code?

Comment: I use [jBCrypt](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt/0.3m) which is really easy to integrate into your application.

Comment: thanks, but what i'm really asking is where to call the hashing function. in the model or in the controller? and how?

Comment: my main problem is that i can't use `@PreUpdate` and `@Prepersist` in ebean.

Comment: FWIW, I do it in the controller (using a utility singleton) when the user changes his/her password or during login. The utility singleton currently uses `Crypto.sign`, but swapping that out for something else would be trivial enough.

Comment: could you provide examples these functions please? i'm having trouble with changing the value for field in form in the controller.
i want to use `.save()` like `userForm.get().save();` and change the value of `password` before save, but i only get the field value with `get()`

Comment: Since I'm working in Scala, I doubt my examples would help you much...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Personally I would do it in the `User` model. I have getters for my fields, so in `setPassword` method:

```
this.password = HashHelper.createPassword(password);
```

The `Hashhelper` is just an singleton class for multi purposes hashing stuff.

And in Hashelper I use BCrypt, just add following to Build.scala

```
org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m
```

And the crypting looks like:

```
/**
 * Create an encrypted password from a clear string.
 * 
 * @param clearString
 *            the clear string
 * @return an encrypted password of the clear string
 * @throws AppException
 *             APP Exception, from NoSuchAlgorithmException
 */
public static String createPassword(String clearString) throws AppException {
    if (clearString == null) {
        throw new AppException("empty.password");
    }
    return BCrypt.hashpw(clearString, BCrypt.gensalt());
}
```

And decrypting looks like:

```
/**
 * Method to check if entered user password is the same as the one that is
 * stored (encrypted) in the database.
 * 
 * @param candidate
 *            the clear text
 * @param encryptedPassword
 *            the encrypted password string to check.
 * @return true if the candidate matches, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean checkPassword(String candidate, String encryptedPassword) {
    if (candidate == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (encryptedPassword == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return BCrypt.checkpw(candidate, encryptedPassword);
}
```

I love to keep my controllers as simple as possible as I see my controllers just as traffic controllers between the user action and the business model (inside my models!) stuff.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, i'd like to keep controllers clean too, i think that this kind of logic should be implemented in model level. i've read somewhere that i've to create getter and setter for all of the class's attributes if i create for one. is this true?

Comment: Although play can works with public properties, I still prefer getters and setters and I experienced strange behavior (value not visible) when using them mixed. But with getters it always works :-)

Comment: I appear to have build.sbt, rather than build.scala.  What's the right  incantation in that case?  Thanks!

Comment: Great answer.   Can you help with what to do if we have build.sbt rather than build.scala?

Comment: And the answer is..   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",  ...

Answer (score 4):

I found a much simpler solution on the web at this adress : 
http://rny.io/playframework/bcrypt/2013/10/22/better-password-hashing-in-play-2.html

First download the jbcrypt-xxx.jar at [this adress](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt/0.3m).

In the libraryDependencies in build.sbt, add :

```
"org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"
```

This is the function to create a new user (located in the model class User) :

```
  public static User create(String userName, String password) {
    User user = new User();
    user.userName = userName;
    user.passwordHash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
    user.save();
    return user;
  }
```

And, still in the User class, the function to authenticate :

```
public static User authenticate(String userName, String password) {
    User user = User.find.where().eq("userName", userName).findUnique();
    if (user != null && BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.passwordHash)) {
      return user;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
```

And it work !