# How to handle exceptions within the Play 2 Framework in java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

How/where should I set up exception handling, so that I can throw a somewhat generic "oops - simply can't deal with this" style of exception and handle it moderately gracefully?

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657062/play-framework-2-best-way-to-store-password-hash-of-user) hints that it should be elegant (AppException), and of course it should but I can't quite figure where the catching should be and how it should cause a subsequent error page render...

(google reveals answers to this in the scala world, but I haven't been able to get my head around what the equivalent is in java).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See "Providing an application error page" here:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/JavaGlobal

It's a global exception handler so you don't need to catch anything.

Note: if you copy&paste provided code, you need to create a new view named "errorPage" that takes one argument of type Throwable. Something like this:

```
@(t: Throwable)

<h1>My Error page</h1>
@t.getMessage
```

Comment: Hah - that was easy :)   Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on where would be the "appropriate" place to declare application-specific exceptions?   Is it in Global.java, also?   (I'm not yet clear on what packages are visible from where within the Play framework, so I don't know whether Global.java is the right place to declare an exception that will be thrown from a model, for example...

Comment: I would put AppException somewhere inside "app/models/common".

Comment: Thanks for your ongoing help.   The code that you point to unfortunately is giving me a hassle: cannot find symbol : class html.   The arrow points to views.html.errorPage(t).    I've tried importing views.html.*, to no avail.   Clues?   Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I've sent you link to an old version of Play framework. Check my answer, I have updated it.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I was on the right course there, thinking I should create that errorPage ... I actually misread the explanation and interpreted it as errorPage _is_ the internal one.  Which it is not.  All sorted now - thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

develop Global.java under default package extending from GlobalSettings and implement onError (-)method , it will handle the exception